# Struts2 iterator with dynamic columns

Tags: struts2

Imagine a POJO "Employee" which has three properties.

```
public Class Employee{
private String id;
private String name;
private double salaray;
}
```

I have a method that fetches list of Employee. In jsp i display the list with  tag.

```
<s:iterator value="listEmployee">
<s:property value="id"/>
<s:property value="name"/>
</s:iterator>
```

As you can see, I have displayed only two columns inside iterator. Now in my case, how do i add the field salary inside iterator dynamically?

This is small example relevant to my actual situation. Can anyone throw some light?

Comment: pls use the "code" button when editing

Comment: it's not clear, why you need "dynamic columns": salary is just a double, or an array or what?

Comment: dynamic in the "rendering/display" sense. Like say the code displays a table with two columns id and name. Now on some action, how do i display the salary column also...?

Comment: Requirements not clear, we do not understand how you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any practical way.  If you set your view up to handle such dynamic objects then it can be done with reflection, although I will recommend [Apache BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.3/apidocs/index.html).

Say you do something like (not tested):

```
public class Introspector{
   private BeanMap properties;

   public Introspector(){
     myProperties = new BeanMap(this);
   }

   public Set getProperties(){
     return properties.keySet();
   }
}
```

With that done, the Employee class should be able to use it...

```
public class Employee extends Introspector{
   private String id;
   private String name;
   private double salaray;
   //getters setters for above properties
}
```

then in the view you could say...

```
<s:iterator value="listEmployee">
   <s:iterator value="properties">
      <s:property>
   </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```